# Is a Timer the best way to achieve recursive in Android?

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm changing the Viewpager items programmatically using `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` with a regular interval of time recursively. Please tell me if this is the best way to achieve this or if there are any problems with my code.

```
    ViewPager mViewPager ;
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(backgroundimages.length), 1, 5000);

    private class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
        int mLength = 0;

        public UpdateTimeTask(final int length) {
            this.mLength = length;
        }

        public void run() {
            mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1 < mLength) {
                        Updateviewpager(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    } else {
                        Updateviewpager(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void Updateviewpager(int position) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timer`s and `TimerTask`s appear to be discouraged for Android, especially when interacting with the UI. Each Timer gets a thread on which to do its work, which makes UI updates problematic, and which also presumably causes unnecessary overhead for small tasks.

This could be updated to use the `postDelayed()` or `postAtTime()` method of `Handler`, which takes advantage of the existing message queue.  Note: this code is not tested.

```
ViewPager mViewPager ;
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

private class UpdateTimeTask implements Runnable {
    private static final int TASK_TIME_MS = 5000;

    private int mLength = 0;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public UpdateTimeTask(final int length) {
        this.mLength = length;
        // Get the main thread's Handler. If the task is
        // always on the main thread, we can just do
        // mHandler = new Handler();
        // Otherwise, do:
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        // Get things started.
        // If this is intended to be done on the UI thread,
        // just call run() directly.
        // run();
        // If this is intended to be done on any thread, use
        // the Handler to execute run()
        mHandler.post(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1 < mLength) {
            Updateviewpager(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        } else {
            Updateviewpager(0);
        }

        // Schedule to repeat
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, TASK_TIME_MS);
    }
}

public void Updateviewpager(int position) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

References: 
[Android Timer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)
[Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developers.androidcn.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)